# JavaScript - Run the designated line of code

Tags: javascript

Hi
Suppose I have a script.js file that contain hundred line of code, could I call this file and **ONLY** run the designated line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create functions in your script file.
You can then call whichever functions you want.

You can even pass parameters!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var script = ... text of your file ...;
var N = ... line number
eval(script.split("\n")[N]);
```

This will execute (evaluate) line #N in your script.